# how do iget an activeform control name in Public Function vb.net2008

Tags: vb.net, controls

i need to get a clicked control name on active form something like

Dim edit As Control = Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Find(sender, Control)

hope some one help me

that's my code

Public Function regfunctionsetrec()

```
Dim strHostName As String
Dim strIPAddress As String

strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()

Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim MYFormName As String = Form.ActiveForm.Name
Dim id As String = " / " + index_ar.ToolStripLabel2.Text
Dim id1 As String = "" '" / " + index_en.ToolStripLabel2.Text
Dim ctrlName As String = DirectCast(Sender, Control).Name
```

Comment: Give some more details please.  Where is this code running?  When you click on a control, it will generate an event.  You can store the sender somewhere so it can be referenced.

Comment: I'm using it in a class as a public function I posted the code below

Comment: You need to read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is not at all the right way to use the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Dim ctrlName As String = Form.ActiveForm.ActiveControl.Name
```